# Getting CloudFront error metrics by origin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a CloudFront distribution that has two origins:

1. S3 (for static content)
2. Akamai GTM (which binds to our frontend load balancers)

CloudFront has metrics like `4xx Error Rate`, `5xx Error Rate`, and `Total Error Rate` at the overall level.

Is it possible to get these metrics broken out by origin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Amazon's documentation, it turns out that the CloudFront metrics are only available at the overall level and not on a per-origin basis:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cf-metricscollected.html

The only way to get some idea of the traffic break up is through access logs.  Remember, enabling access logs comes with a separate S3 cost.

Access logs give no indication of which origin was used. You do have the URI and HTTP response code of every request on which you can count totals based on the routes attached to your origins.

Comment: I like your suggestion about using access logs. Turns out that the metrics are only available at the overall level, and not per origin.  Amazon documentation confirms it: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cf-metricscollected.html

Comment: Just updated the answer to include the info in my above comment.